# Using startswith() function inside lists in python

Tags: python, list

I had the list with following strings below

```
some_list = ['9196358485','9966325645','8846853128','8-4-236/2','9-6-32/45','Need to fetch some strings']
```

From the above strings i want only strings that does n't start with `91,9,8` but want  strings starting with `8-, 9-`

so below is my code

```
[i for i in some_list if all(not i.startswith(x) for x in ['91','8','9'])]
```

**result**:

```
['Need to fetch some strings']
```

In the above by using `['91','8','9']` as the condition is deleting the strings starting with `9 and 8` which is correct, but i don't want `9-, 8-` also to be removed from the list, actually my intension is if the strings starting with `9 and 8` should be ignored as above and strings starting with `9- and 8-` should not be ignored , can we write two conditions in a single line with concept of taking strings starting with `8-,9-` and ignoring when strings starts with `9 or 8` in the above code i had written.

Can anyone please let me know hoe to do this.............

**Edited code:**

Thanks for  all of u r support if u don't think this is another question i had some actual output on which the below code is not working

```
some_list = ['Mr K V  Prasad Reddy(MD)',
 '+(91)-9849633132, 9959455935',
 '+(91)-9849633132',
 'Near NRI College,Opp Vijaya Bank,Nizam Pet Road,Nizampet,Hyderabad - 502102',
 '9196358485',
 '9966325645', 
 '8846853128',
 '8-4-236/2',
 '9-6-32/45',
 'Need to fetch some strings']
```

When i apply the bwlow code using regex i got following output
**result:**

```
['Mr K V  Prasad Reddy(MD)',
 '+(91)-9849633132, 9959455935',
 '+(91)-9849633132',
 'Near NRI College,Opp Vijaya Bank,Nizam Pet Road,Nizampet,Hyderabad - 502102',
 '8-4-236/2',
 '9-6-32/45',
 'Need to fetch some strings']
```

Actually i don't want all phone numbers from the list, so they will be in the above format sometimes starting with `91` sometimes `8` sometimes `9`

How can we remove all those phone numbers from the list?

Comment: yes in the regular expression given below how to avoid string starting with +(91)

Comment: I mean how to ignore strings staring with +(91) and 9 and 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> [i for i in some_list if not re.match(r"[98]\B|+\(91\)", i)]
['8-4-236/2', '9-6-32/45', 'Need to fetch some strings']
```

`\B` matches only within alphanumeric strings, so it matches between `9` and `1` but not between `9` and `-`.

Comment: If you explicitly want to check for a dash after 9 or 8, you could also use the regex `[98](?!-)`.

Comment: Actually that worked but i had pasted a real example above can u please view that

Comment: by using the above code only the strings starting with 8 and 9 are ignored but what if i also the strings starting with +(91) need to be ignored